# How to use UserCredential in ASP.NET Core MVC web application?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, oauth-2.0, google-api, youtube-data-api

I have a small issue creating a user credential (oauth 2.0) for implementing youtube-data api (video upload) in my .NET Core app.

In a console app I download the credential file from google and use it like that:

```
UserCredential credential;

using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Gaby\source\repos\Youtube Api\client.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                "user", CancellationToken.None);
}
```

However I tried to use the same code in an ASP.NET Core MVC app, but I get this error:

> Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project. [401]

And to implement this credential I use this code sample:

```
 var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the same code in the Asp.Net core app It works!